# Does Rails 3.x change link_to behavior when link target is an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm upgrading my Ruby on Rails application from Rails 2.3.11 to 3.1.1. After updating my routes file with the new syntax, I'm seeing a change in behavior of the `link_to` method when passing an ActiveRecord object as the link destination.

Here is an example of an old (non-RESTful) route from my 2.3 application's routes.rb:

```
map.with_options :controller => 'widget' do |widget|
    widget.widget 'widget/show/:id', :action => 'show'
end
```

Here is what this route became in my 3.1 file:

```
scope "widget", :controller => :widget do
    match "show/:id", :action => "show", :as => :widget
  end
end
```

The output of `rake routes` is similar. 2.3:

`widget    /widget/show(/:id)    {:controller=>"widget", :action=>"show"}`

3.1:

`widget    /widget/show/:id(.:format)    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"widget"}`

What's different is that now my link_to calls that look like this:

`link_to("Text", @widget_object)`

Produce this error message:

`Routing Error: No route matches { :controller=>"widget", :action=>"show", :id=>#<Widget id: 123, .....> }`

After seeing this passage in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects):

> <%= link_to "Magazine details", @magazine %>...This allows you to treat instances of your models as URLs, and is a key advantage to using the resourceful style."

my guess is that Rails 2.3 happily handled my `link_to`s because my route's name was "widget" (changing the name would cause my 2.3 app's `link_to`s to break as well), but Rails 3 insists on RESTful/resourceful routes if you're going to use this `link_to` style.

Is that right? I've started refactoring and adding the necessary RESTful routes to make my `link_to`s work again — with good results — but I want to confirm that I really understand the problem. I opened [a thread on the rubyonrails-talk list](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/9214c731fc39799f) but have had no replies yet.

Answer (score 1):

As you're not using the regular set up for your Widget resource, which would be:

```
resources :widgets
```

Rails doesn't where know where the url for @magazine should point. You need to be explicit:

```
link_to "Text", widget_path(@widget_object)
```

Comment: Can you tell me whether this behavior is different as of 3.x? That's what I really want to know. See the last two paragraphs of my question.

Comment: No you still have to specify the path if you're not using `resources`

Comment: Can you tell me whether this behavior is different as of 3.x? That's what I really want to know.